# Issues with syncing one drive intiailly

Tags: windows, sharepoint, microsoft-office-365

I manage this business with about 30-50 computers and mobile devices all with one drive/sharepoint through office 365.

When I try and setup a new sync on computers, about half the time I get file conflict issues. I have to go in and delete the files then I can sync the computer and then add the files back.

Is this a common issue to happen or what can I do to prevent having file conflicts all the time. It seems like if one file conflicts the entire onedrive syncing just stops in general for that device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always had trouble with the old OneDrive for Business client, users stopped syncing completely because of file conflicts and I was always forced to remove/fix/resync the entire local folders.

Things can't get any better after switching to the new OneDrive for Business Next Generation client, not a single error over 2 months of use.

Check it out here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Improve-your-OneDrive-sync-experience-7af500d9-a18e-4abb-8450-b94f4e52c1a0

Edit: A new version is coming out very soon: https://blogs.office.com/2016/04/12/onedrive-for-business-recognized-as-an-efss-leader-and-continues-momentum-with-spring-updates/#6KD7Jv9Gqv8tQPGi.97

Thanks @Jesus Shelby for the heads up.

Comment: Well that looks like a headache full of confusion. Typical Microsoft though. I'll have to give that a try

Comment: The next gen client will start rolling out next month officially.  MS is updating the client so you don't need the registry update.  It is however a new install - so it won't be updated thru the normal Office update.